# How do you convert a bearing (in degrees) to a gradient (slope) using R?

Tags: r, trigonometry

I wish to convert a bearing to a gradient, say "045" to 1. My code is as follows:

```
bearing = 
grad = 1/tan(bearing)
```

There are two problems

- It assumes bearing is in radians
- the equation would fail where the bearing is any multiple of 90

How can I change r to read in degrees (or would I just have to convert it myself) and how would I go about avoiding the cases where the bearing is a multiple of 90

Some examples of expected input and output are as follows:

```
000 -> Inf 
062 -> 1.88
180 -> -Inf
301 -> -1.66
```

Comment: You can easily convert radians to degrees with: degrees = radians × 180° / π

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem of the multiples of 90°

Comment: `degrees <- degrees %% 90`?

Comment: Which equation would fail? If you include 45,90,180, or any number as bearing in your second equation, you still get a result, although it might not be correct.

Comment: Can you please provide some example of bearings and expected output?

Comment: 000 -> Inf, 062 -> 1.88, 180 -> -Inf, 301 -> -1.66

Comment: If you dont care about positive or negative `Inf` you could include this condition: `if (any(bearing %% 90 == 0)) {
  bearing[bearing %% 90 == 0] = 0
}`

Answer (score 0):

The following functions will convert bearings to gradient

```
library(dplyr)

dtr <- function(degrees) { degrees * (pi/180) } # Converts degrees to radians 

btg <- function(bearing) {

  if( bearing > 180 ) { bearing <- bearing - 180 } # Since the gradient of bearing x and x - 180 are the same when x > 180

  if( bearing == 0 ) { gradient <- Inf } # Replace Inf with NA_character_ if preferred
  if( bearing == 90 ) { gradient <- 0 }
  if( bearing == 180 ) { gradient <- Inf }

  if( !bearing %in% c(0, 90, 180)) {

    if(bearing < 90 ) {
      gradient <- sin(dtr(90 - bearing)) / sin(dtr(180-bearing))
    }

    if(bearing > 90 ) {
      gradient <- (sin(dtr(90 - bearing)) / sin(dtr(180-bearing)))
    }

  }

  return(gradient)
}
```

E.g.

```
bearings <- c(30, 45, 90, 135, 170, 179, 180, 235, 250, 290, 360) # We can test the btg function on some bearings

for (i in 1:length(bearings)) {

  gradients[i] <- btg(bearings[i])

}

data.frame(bearings, gradients)
```